# Using Keras for stock prices

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am a newbie to using Keras. Have adapted a code in Python and tried to use it together with the stock prices downloaded from Yahoo Finance.

For some reason, I think the code is not running properly. During the run, the loss and accuracy is zero. I suspect it is because the code was created for binary outputs (as I adapted it straight from the Keras website).

Data is from [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/0001.HK/history?p=0001.HK)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_original = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Work/Test Python/TestTensorflow/Data/0001_HK.csv')
data_length = len(data_original)
x_original = data_original['close']
x = x_original[0:data_length-2]
x1 = x_original[1:data_length-1]
x = np.reshape(x.as_matrix(),(len(x),1))
x1 = np.reshape(x1.as_matrix(),(len(x),1))
x = np.append(x,x1,axis = 1)

y = data_original['close']
y = y[2:data_length]
y = np.reshape(y.as_matrix(),(len(y),1))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size = 0.3,random_state = 42)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          epochs=20)
score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=128)
```

The aim of the code is simply to take the trailing 2 days of price data and use it to predict the next day's price.

Anyone knows what modifications I need to make? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. There was an error in the inputs. Case closed.